# Why would an R function not write to the environment?

Tags: r, for-loop, graph, plot, autoregressive-models

I'm trying to write a relatively simple AR(1) representation in R. I cannot find any glaring issues with this code, and furthermore I am returning not errors, it simple isn't writing to the environment, or recognizing areone2 as a function. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
areone2<-function(y,N,p,d){
  yvec<-c(rep(y, times = N))
  for(i in 1:N){
    yvec[i+1]<-
      ((1+p*(yvec[i]-d))
      + d)
               }
  plot(yvec, type='l', xlab="N", ylab="yeild")
                          }

areone2(.3,10,.9,.2)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because you broke the line in `yvec[i+1]<-
      ((1+p*(yvec[i]-d))
      + d)`

Comment: Tried that too, nothing changed unfortunately

Comment: I don't really understand. This threw no error, it did create a plot, and your code shows not effort to send a message to the console. So where exactly was the problem??? You are the one who "didn't write to the environment". If you wanted a value rerurned from the function they you a) should have done so and b) would have needed to assign it to a symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't trigger an error or warning because you broke the line in the middle of a binary operation, but that binary operation wasn't recognized by the parser.  It's perfectly  legal to begin a line with `+ 3` It's just `3`, which is not what you want.

For example, 2 + 3 is 5, we would expect.  But +3 on a new line does not add it to the previous line

```
> 2        ## break the line here and R returns 2
[1] 2
> +3       ## adding three next is not recognized as a continuation of a call
[1] 3
```

But you can still break the line if you wrap the call in parentheses (not brackets)

```
(2 
 + 3)
# [1] 5   ## correct
{2 
 + 3} 
# [1] 3   ## incorrect
```

Bringing your `yvec[]<-` assignment call up onto one line is the  cleaner and safer way to go.

```
yvec[i+1] <- ((1+p*(yvec[i]-d)) + d)
```